# how to run perl script on Execute process task in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to execute perl script in the SSIS task. I Have one csv file contains the persons name

For Example:
John,Male,London
Mary,Female

i want to load the data to table, that table having unique id for Example:
100,Peter,Male
101,Roy,Male
102,John,Male

i have one perl script it will give the person's location. For Example: am running the script through command line

perl location.pl Mary(Parameter: Through variable)
Result: Mary,Female,Paris

i will use lookup the person name is there in the database or not.

Kindly Help me the step how to use Execute process task and to execute perl script, perl script output to load into database

Answer (score 2):

probably calling it from a script task is the easiest:

```
    Dim par As String = Dts.Variables("YourSSISVariable").ToString()
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
    p.FileName = "C:\Perl.exe" ' <-------------- Make sure is the right perl location
    p.Arguments = par
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    Process.Start(p)

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

you may need to declare "YourSSISVariable" on the SSIS package and add it to the Script Task properties as ReadOnlyVariable

Comment: You just need to extend this script to pick up `Mary,Female,Paris` from the console and return it as a recorset to SSIS.